# Kerberos administrator authorization

Tags: c++, authorization, kerberos

I'm writing linux application that integrates with MS Active Directory. For this purpose I'm using Kerberos. I've already implemented mechanism that authenticates domain user with given credentials, but now I want to check if user is member of administrators group.

So I have `creds` obtained from the function.

```
error = krb5_get_init_creds_password(context, &creds, principals,
        password.c_str(), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

And here I want to implement logic that authorizes user/administrator

```
if(!error) {
    // admin check
}
```

I'm thinking of using the `krb5_verify_init_creds` function but I'm not sure how can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kerberos does not do authorization, only authentication. (i.e. it can figure out who you are, but not what you are allowed to do).

In general, once you have the kerberos ID, you would ask some authorization service what that ID is allowed to do. In this case, the most straightforward thing to do is to make an ldap query to find out if the user is a member in the group you are interested in.

MS kerberos violates this principle by adding extra group information that AD knows about to the kerberos service tickets. However, I am not aware of any standard kerberos API's that provide access to this information.

Answer (score 2):

As Fred noted, Kerberos is for authentication, not for authorization. While Kerberos ticket issued by an AD DC contains MS-PAC record with additional information about membership of the AD object mapped to this Kerberos principal, you need more than just knowing format of the records presented in the ticket to make use of it.

In a typical Linux environment your application is better to rely on PAM stack to decouple authentication and authorization steps. Typically a PAM session setup is used to run authorization checks. If your Linux machines are configured to use SSSD (either with `id_provider = ad` or with `id_provider=ipa` and cross-forest trust between FreeIPA and AD), you can rely on `pam_sss` to handle both authentication and authorization steps via SSSD.

Recent versions of SSSD support GPO-based access by mapping GPO logon rights to PAM services.

With SSSD your AD users and groups would be presented as POSIX users and groups. This allows you to build a simple access control based on the group membership that you can obtain via `getgrouplist(3)` call after you mapped Kerberos principal to local user name with `krb5_aname_to_localname()`.

If you still need to know additional information about the user mapped from Kerberos principal, you can utilize infopipe interface of SSSD. The information available through infopipe is gathered from both Kerberos ticket (when available) and AD LDAP (Global Catalog or DC directly). By using infopipe you wouldn't need to resolve SIDs in MS-PAC to names, resolve group membership and verify signatures of the MS-PAC and other components of the ticket as SSSD does it for you. See https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/DesignDocs/DBusResponder and http://www.adelton.com/apache/mod_lookup_identity/ for practical implementation.